# HTML5 form button onsubmit not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple form with two HTML5 buttons. Each button submits the form to a different php page. This is working well, but the 'onsubmit' function is never triggered. I want to show a dialog box before the delete.php page is called.

```
<form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="fname">

      <!-- HTML5 FORMACTION -->
      <button type="submit" name="update" formaction="update.php">Update</button>
      <button type="submit" name="delete" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete?');" formaction="delete.php">Delete</button>
  </form>
```

I have tried different variations, but the javascript code is never triggered. Why?

Comment: Try with `onclick`. I don't think `<button>` has an `onsubmit` event, only `form` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
<form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="fname">

      <!-- HTML5 FORMACTION -->
      <button type="submit" name="update" formaction="update.php">Update</button>
      <button type="button" name="delete" onclick="return delete();" formaction="delete.php">Delete</button>
  </form>

<script>
function delete(){

if(confirm('Do you really want to delete?')){
// delete code
}
return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Buttons don't have submit events, forms do.

Buttons have click events.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it could do with some more information.

Comment: Since the HTML5 button can override formaction, I also expected it to be able to override onsubmit... onclick suggests that it's not connected to submitting. But it works nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

`onsubmit` is valid for a `form`, not for a button. You will have to use `onclick` instead of `onsubmit`.